# How to find commutative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to find a solution here.
When it is given a matrix without any element equal to 0 for example:

[image]
it is easy to find his commutative matrix but when it is given a matrix with some elements equal to zero for example:

[image]
I'm not sure how to find his commutative matrix.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I mean a matrix B such that AB=BA.

Comment: Hmm, $$\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\c&d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a+2c & b+2d\\0&0\end{pmatrix};\quad \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1&2\\0&0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & 2a\\c &2c\end{pmatrix}$$ So $c = 0$ and $b+2d = 2a$.

Comment: In this case, one says, a matrix that commutes with him, instead of his commutative matrix. :)

Answer (score 4):

Note that if $A$ is a square matrix then $A$ commutes with $I,A,A^2,A^3,\dots$ and so with any polynomial $c_0I+c_1A+c_2A^2+\cdots+a_rA^r$ in $A$. Most of the time, those are the only matrices that commute with $A$.

If $A$ is $n\times n$, then (by Cayley-Hamilton) all powers of $A$ can be expressed in terms of $I,A,A^2,\dots,A^{n-1}$. In particular, for $n=2$, $A$ will commute with all matrices of the form $aI+bA$ and, in most cases, with nothing else.

A complete answer can be given in terms of Jordan canonical form.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
AB
&=
\overbrace{\left(a + \vec{b}\cdot\vec{\sigma}\right)}^{A}\,
\overbrace{\left(a' + \vec{b}'\cdot\vec{\sigma}\right)}^{B}
=
aa' + \vec{b}\cdot\vec{b}'
+
\left(a\vec{b}' + a'\vec{b}
+
{\rm i}\,\vec{b}\times\vec{b}'\right)\cdot\vec{\sigma}
\\[3mm]
BA
&=
\left(a' + \vec{b}'\cdot\vec{\sigma}\right)
\left(a + \vec{b}\cdot\vec{\sigma}\right)
=
a'a + \vec{b}'\cdot\vec{b}
+
\left(a'\vec{b} + a\vec{b}'
+
{\rm i}\,\vec{b}'\times\vec{b}\right)\cdot\vec{\sigma}
\end{align}

$$
AB - BA
=
2{\rm i}\,\vec{b}\times\vec{b}'
=
0
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\vec{b}' = \mu\vec{b}
$$

> Given a $2\times 2$ matrix $A \equiv a + \vec{b}\cdot\vec{\sigma}$, all the matrix
> of the form $a' + \mu\vec{b}\cdot\vec{\sigma}$ commutes with $A$.

For example:
\begin{align}
A
&=
\left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2
\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
=
\left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
{1 \over 2} & 0
\\
0 & {1 \over 2}
\end{array}\right)
+
\left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
{1 \over 2} & 2
\\
0 & -\,{1 \over 2}
\end{array}\right)
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over 2}
+
\left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1
\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
+
{\rm i}\,\left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -{\rm i}
\\
{\rm i} & 0
\end{array}\right)
+
{1 \over 2}
\left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0
\\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right)
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over 2}
+
\sigma_{x} + {\rm i}\sigma_{y} + {1 \over 2}\sigma_{z}
=
{1 \over 2} + \left(1, {\rm i}, {1 \over 2}\right)\cdot\vec{\sigma} 
\end{align}

Then,
$$
\color{#ff0000}{\large B}
=
\nu + \mu\left(1, {\rm i}, {1 \over 2}\right)\cdot\vec{\sigma}
=
\nu
+
\mu\,\left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
{1 \over 2} & 2
\\
0 & -\,{1 \over 2}
\end{array}\right)
=
\color{#ff0000}{\large%
\left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
\nu + {1 \over 2}\,\mu & 2\mu
\\
0 & \nu -\,{1 \over 2}\,\mu
\end{array}\right)}
$$

$\displaystyle{\vec{\sigma}_{i}}$ is a $\tt\mbox{Pauli matrix}$.
$\displaystyle{i \equiv x, y, z.\quad}$
$\displaystyle{\vec{\sigma} \equiv \sum_{i = x, y, z}\sigma_{i}\,e_{i}\quad}$
is the $\tt\mbox{Pauli matrix vector}.\quad$
$\displaystyle{e_{x} \equiv \hat{x},\quad e_{y} \equiv \hat{y},\quad e_{z} \equiv \hat{z}}$.